# Как перебрать массив и заменить в нем текст?

Tags: python, замена

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь освоить Python. Вопрос: как заменить в строке совпадения?
У меня все время ошибка :(

```
def create_config(file, array , outfile):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        f = open(file)
        o = open(outfile,'a')
        while 1:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break

            for key, value in array.items():
                line = line.replace(key, value)

            o.write(line)
        o.close()
    else:
        print('mongodb.conf does not exist')
h1 = {'dbpath':'= /opt/mongo', 'logpath':"= /mongo/zzz", 3:"three"}

create_config('1', h1 , '22')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
>     line2 = line.replace(key, value)
> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Такой строки нет в приведенном коде:  

    line2 = line.replace(key, value)

Comment: Попробовал ошибка та же, ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ, СПАСИБО!

Comment: `ConfigParser` стандартный модуль можно использовать, чтобы работать с конфигами с простым ini-форматом.

Comment: @Алексей Сидорин, не по вопросу, но думаю вам пригодится.
Вот эти три строки

        while 1:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break

легко превращаются в одну:

    for line in f:

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что ругается на ключ 3. Попробуйте приводить тип:

```
line = line.replace(str(key), str(value))
```

int на это должен отреагировать вполне спокойно.

Comment: @Алексей Сидорин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0):

В Питоне строки и числа принадлежат к разным типам. `line.replace` принимает только строки.

Питон 3 использует более информативное сообщение об ошибке:

```
>>> ''.replace(3, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Если `h1` словарь используется только в `create_config()` функции, тогда можно изменить его определение, чтобы он не содержал не строковых значений:

```
h1 = {'dbpath': '= /opt/mongo', 'logpath': '= /mongo/zzz', '3':' three'}
```

В слепую `str()` лучше не вызывать, это может скрыть баги, такие как смешивание юникодных и бинарных строк, -- на ascii-вводе такая программа будет работать, но сломается в общем случае.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_config(file, array , outfile):

    # Имитация чтения с файла. Типа line = f.readline()
    for line in ('dbpath','logpath','3'):

        for key, value in array.items():
            new_line = line
            new_line = line.replace(key, value)
            # Если данных много и они не повторяются лучще зделать так
            if new_line != line: #Если значение изменено, то цикл прерывается, а не работает дальше в пустую
                print(line,' => ', new_line)
                break

h1 = {'dbpath':'= /opt/mongo', 'logpath':"= /mongo/zzz", '3':"three"}

create_config('1', h1 , '22')
```